# What does <~~ mean in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

While checking a parser of a JSON in swift, I found the following code:

```
description = "desc" <~~ json
```

I suppose that it is similar to use the following:

```
description = json["desc"]
```

Is it correct? if no, what does this operator mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right. But it would be wrong to assume that's what it is set out to do in Swift.

I think the parser that was being used was Gloss, and it seems that they have written an operator overload specifically to mean `description = json["desc"]` (and or or some other stuff under the hood to make the parsing easier) . The operator does not have a meaning *per se* in Swift. But it's invented by the framework to do the parsing.

You can read about operator overloading [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/80818/operator-overloading-in-swift-tutorial)

**EDIT**

I always have incorrectly used the terms operator overloading and defining custom operator interchangeably. Operator Overloading is *extending the implementation of the existing operators* which is different than defining your own custom operators. Thank you SO MUCH for pointing this out, @Giacomo Alzetta!

Comment: Thanks a lot :), and yes they are using Gloss

Comment: Great! Does that answer your question, though?

Comment: I find your answer confusing. That is not operator *overloading*, that is **defining** a *custom operator*. Many languages support custom operators (e.g. Haskell. If you want something crazy check out Maude...). Your sentence "This operator does not have a meaning per se in Swift" is the same as saying "The function my_function_123 does not have a meaning per se in Swift". Operators are just fancy function names that have infix call syntax...